# Where do I put the Alias?

Tags: linux, unix, alias, bashrc

```
alias py='python'
```

Do I put that in my .bashrc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes if you want to work for your use only then yes .bashrc is the right file. If you want it to work globally add it in /etc/bash.bashrc

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of aliases it can be a good idea to have a special file for them (like *~/.bash.aliases*) and source that in your *~/.bashrc*

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Don't forget to reopen your session. :-)

Comment: Or just `$ source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Or just `$ . ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Yes, sure :) Or just execute the same command in the shell.